# Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void Makesum(Integer, Integer)

Tags: apex, community

```
public class Vinay {

    private integer VarSum;
    private integer VarMultiplication;

    public integer Makesum(integer VarNumA,integer VarNumB){
        VarSum = VarNumA + VarNumB;
        return VarSum;
    }

}
```

```
Vinay sampleobject = New Vinay();
integer Vartemp = sampleobject.Makesum(10,20);
system.debug('the resut is ='+ Vartemp);
```

Comment: In such configuration everything works fine. Assuming you're calling the second sample from Dev Console. Please, add some details or make sure you have saved class in this state (with method declared).

Comment: @MariiaIllarionova Thank you very much its working fine after saving .